# Concurrent Recording and Playback of Video on an SBC (RasPi Zero or C.H.I.P.)

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, arm, embedded-linux, raspbian

I'm looking to judge the feasibility of simultaneous recording and playback of two 720p A/V streams using an inexpensive Single-Board Computer. To clarify, I want to present a prerecorded 720p video to a user while simultaneously recording a 720p video of their reaction to it.

I've designed a solution based on specialised video processors / encoders (F1C100 and NT96632BG) and multiple multiplexed flash memory banks, but implementing it would greatly exceed the project's up-front development budget.

The only off-the-shelf hardware I know of that *might* do the trick *and* fall within both target BOM and development costs would be an SBC.

Any help judging feasibility (and if possible, implementation suggestions) would be most appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP is searching for a subcontractor, not an answer.

Comment: @TolgaEvcimen Okay, forget the request for a subcontractor if that violates the rules. I'll code it myself if somebody can offer a strategy that will work. Or I'll recruit elsewhere if the solution is low-level enough that I can't reasonably do that. I was just hoping to motivate those who might have an answer based on proprietary knowledge that they wouldn't otherwise share.

Comment: @TolgaEvcimen it's rather unfair to say that I'm not looking for an answer just because I said I was open to something else in addition. One doesn't preclude the other, thank you very much. I am very definitely looking for an answer.

Comment: Even so, your question is too broad to answer, and looking for an opinion rather than a solution.

Comment: Besides the video spatial resolution, you need to specify the video codec and compression level.  That affects the I/O bandwidth that is required.

Comment: @sawdust I'm open to any codec and compression level. Am I correct in assuming that I/O bandwidth demands will be inversely proportional to CPU demands?